# Why does FFMPEG different arguments' placement create different mov clips?

Tags: command-line, video, ffmpeg, video-editing

I use `ffmpeg` to cut the first 4 seconds of a `mov` 14 seconds video file.

This is the command I use (on Ubuntu) to create the new clip:

```
ffmpeg -i H264_test1_Talkinghead_mov_480x360.mov -ss 0 -t 4 -c copy test_1_seg.mov
```

Alas, with this command, even though I can hear the audio from the start of the new clip, the video starts showing only from ~1 second.

However, if I change the arguments' order in the command slightly, I can see the video from the start:

```
ffmpeg -ss 0 -t 4 -i H264_test1_Talkinghead_mov_480x360.mov -c copy  test_1_1_seg.mov
```

**1. Any idea why the order of arguments matters?
 
 2. Is that a bug/feature? 

 3. Can other arguments' placement have impact on `ffmpeg` output?**

---

The original (14 seconds) file is [test.mov](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bw5McUt95YdeVlp0bG9fZmtjQnM)
The faulty new clip (first 4 seconds) file is [test_1_seg.mov](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bw5McUt95YdeUDFTQjFJVEtHNmc)
The correct new clip (first 4 seconds) file is [test_1_1_seg.mov](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bw5McUt95YdeRE5vSWt2Q1kxWk0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html

The two arguments "-ss" and "-t" serve different purposes if you use it as in input or an output option. Wether of both it is is set if they stand before the "-i" or before the output file.

Comment: Thanks. After reading https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options, it's clear now.